# Primefaces in Intellij do not show

Tags: jsf, intellij-idea, jsf-2, primefaces

I am trying to get Primefaces to work in IntelliJ. I have the ultimate edition (15.0.5) that supports web development and normal JSF works without problems when running on Wildfly 10.

When I create a new project I select Primefaces and it downloads the binary and places it in the lib/ directory. I add xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui" to the index.xhtml and code completion works for Primefaces (I add a  just for testing).

Other questions on this topic have said to add

```
<servlet-mapping>
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
   <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And this is already the case when I create a new web project.

The code I try to run is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
   <f:view>
      <h:outputLabel value="Hello, world"/><br/>
      <p:editor />
   </f:view>
</html>
```

When looking at the source in the web browser I get this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"><label>Hello, world</label><br />
      <p:editor></p:editor>
</html>
```

So for some reason that I am unable to find out, Primefaces are not found. I have searched for an answer, and followed tutorials, but I have not found anything that helps me with this.

Everything works flawlessly when I create a project using Eclipse instead, but I would rather use IntelliJ...

Lastly, I am running IntelliJ on Ubuntu 15.10 using Oracle's Java.

Any ideas?

Comment: Wait, I didn't understand something. You mean your project WHILE running is not rendering the PrimeFaces stuff?

Comment: Yes, exactly -- nothing shows up when running the project on Wildfly. I visit the page (or rather, when "running" from IntelliJ it opens up the page when deployment is done) nothing is shown from Primefaces.

Comment: This looks like a problem with dependencies not being deployed or missing. It probably has nothing to do with Intellij.

Comment: Okay, I can understand that -- but what do I do about it? How do I deploy it in that case?

Comment: Are you sure you have primefaces jar on your `\WEB-INF\lib\` folder?

Comment: You are quite right there, it was not. I tried to copy it to that location as well and things turned out differently -- however not as I wanted. The editor is not showing, but the code on the when looking at the source is now different:
<div id="j_idt4" style="visibility:hidden"><textarea id="j_idt4_input" name="j_idt4_input"></textarea></div><script id="j_idt4_s" type="text/javascript">$(function(){PrimeFaces.cw("Editor","widget_j_idt4",{id:"j_idt4",widgetVar:"widget_j_idt4"},"editor");});</script>
</html>

Comment: I guess now it would be a different question all together.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the default location where the libraries are stored. IntelliJ puts it into /lib for some reason instead of /web/WEB-INF/lib.
You can correct this in File > Project Structure > Libraries. Select Primefaces and then the jar under classes. Select Change Version... and specify the Copy downloaded files to folder to /web/WEB-INF/lib.

I added a screenshot:
[Change folder to WEB-INF/lib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xV4cY.png)

Another Solution is to modify the build process. Select from main menu: Build > Build Artifacts... > Your Artifact > Edit
Then on the Output Layout select Primefaces under Available Elements > right click > Add to WEB-INF/lib.

[Modify Build Artifact](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k0SFC.png)